# Issuer is Invalid when calling ASP.NET Core 2.2 from Angular 7 (MSAL)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

ASP.NET Core 2.2 Application with Azure AD B2C (using URL Endpooint v2.0):

I configured my core application as follows AppSettings.js:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp",
  "ClientId": "{ClientIdGuid}",
  "Domain": "{Subdomain}.onmicrosoft.com",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignInDevelopment"
}
```

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADB2CBearer(o => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", o));    
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc(o=>{o.MapRoute(name:"d",template:"{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");});   
}
```

My Angular 7 client uses MSAL with the following settings:

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
  clientID: environment.azureB2CClientID,
  authority: "https://" + environment.azureTenantIDSubdomain + ".b2clogin.com/tfp/" +
    environment.azureTenantIDSubdomain + ".onmicrosoft.com/" +
    environment.azureSignUpSignInPolicyId + "/v2.0",
  redirectUri: environment.schemeAndAuthority + "/home",
  validateAuthority: false,
  cacheLocation : "localStorage",
  postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.schemeAndAuthority + "/",
  popUp: false
}),
```

which when calling the APIs generates this Bearer JWT:

```
"exp": 1547479156,
"nbf": 1547475556,
"ver": "1.0",
"iss": "https://{Subdomain}.b2clogin.com/{Guid1}/v2.0/",
"sub": "{Guid2}",
"aud": "{Guid3}",
"nonce": "{Guid4}",
"iat": 1547475556,
"auth_time": 1547475556,
"oid": "{Guid5}",
"tfp": "B2C_1_SignUpSignInDevelopment"
```

And my .well-known looks like this: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Subdomain}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignInDevelopment/.well-known/openid-configuration

```
{
  "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ClientGuid}/",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{Subdomain}.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignindevelopment/oauth2/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{Subdomain}.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignindevelopment/oauth2/token",
    ...
}
```

Whenever I am calling my `[Authorize]` protected API Controler (ASP.NET Core 2.2), I am getting 401:

```
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer is invalid"
```

I realized that the Issuer in the .well-known is different than that of the generated Bearer JWT. But I have not set the issuer on Angular side nor on the Azure AD B2C side.

**Is this problem caused by different issuers on Angular and Azure AD B2C sides? And if so, which issuer should I change and how?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must ensure the issuer domains are consistent for both the client application and the API application; otherwise, the client application is issued an access token for one issuer domain and the API application is validating it for another issuer domain.

You are using `{tenant}.b2clogin.com` for the client application and `login.microsoftonline.com` for the API application.

I suggest you use `{tenant}.b2clogin.com` for both.